# Why did my string not cast into an int? I used Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java, string, casting, integer

When I run my code I get an error that says

"DigitExtractor1.java:41: error: bad operand types for binary operator '%'
oneDigit = (byte)(userInput % 10);
^
first type:  String
second type: int"

Im not sure where it went wrong. I thought when I casted the string to an int, it became an int?
intCastFrmString = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DigitExtractor1{
   
   public static void main(String[]args){
      
      //variables
      final int PERIOD_UNICODE = (int) ('.');
      String userInput;
      int intCastFrmString;
      byte oneDigit;
      boolean validInput;
      
      //scanner object
      Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
      userInput = x.nextLine();
      
      //loop to collect input from the user
      if (userInput.indexOf(PERIOD_UNICODE) != -1){
         validInput = false;
         System.out.println("Input is a floating pt number; try again: ");
         
      }else{
         validInput = true;
         System.out.println(userInput + " is a vlaid integer");
         //string to an int
         intCastFrmString = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
      }
      
      //loop to extract and display the digits in int
      System.out.println("Extracted digits of: " + userInput);
      do{
         //determine rightmost digit
         oneDigit = (byte)(userInput % 10);
         
         //if oneDig is neg, display purposes, take abs val
         if(oneDigit < 0)
            oneDigit *= -1;
            
         //display digit
         System.out.println(oneDigit);
         
         //reduce the int by factor of ten
         userInput /= 10;
      }while(userInput != 0);

   }
}
```

Comment: You would need to use your casted value in the calculation: ```oneDigit = (byte)(intCastFrmString % 10);``` It's because you're using the string input in the calculation.

Comment: https://javaranch.com/ is a great website for beginners

Answer (score 1):

You are using userInput, which has the type string, in `oneDigit = (byte)(userInput % 10);`, `userInput /= 10;`, and `userInput != 0` instead of the int intCastFromString.

Comment: After changing them to that, it says intCastFrmString might not have be initialized? Do I move the casting outside the if statement where I have it at?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use br.readLine() and then convert it to int using type casting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).